# Get the access/visibility modifier of each method

Tags: php, oop, methods, access-modifiers

Is there a way to know the type (sorry if this is not the correct name) of a method inside a object? Imagine you have an object with 5 methods, 3 of them being public and the remaining protected / private, how can you know if a method is public?

Cheers!

Comment: "The **[visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)** of a property or method can be defined by prefixing the declaration with the keywords _public_, _protected_ or _private_."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use reflection for getting info about classes and objects.
Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('TestClass');
$aMethods = $reflection->getMethods(); 
var_dump($aMethods[0]->isPublic());
```